# Airflow bigquery_to_gcs operator changing field_delimiter

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to use Airflow operator  BigQueryToGCSOperator & forcing **field_delimiter** to be pipe (|) , however output of the file is always coming comma (,) delimited.

I have also tried operator BigQueryToCloudStorageOperator which has same behavior.

Any idea what wrong I am doing here ?

```py
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.bigquery_to_gcs import (
    BigQueryToGCSOperator,
  
data_to_gcs = BigQueryToGCSOperator(
        task_id="BigQuery_to_GoogleCloudBucket",
        gcp_conn_id="google_cloud_default",
        project_id=project_id,
        source_project_dataset_table=f"{project_id}.{temp_dataset_id}.{temp_table}",
        location="EU",
        print_header=True,
        destination_cloud_storage_uris=destination_uri,
        export_format="csv",
        field_delimiter="|",
    )
```

Thanks in advance for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally if you set the `export_format` field with `CSV` (uppercase instead of lower case) and `field_delimiter` it should work :

```py
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.bigquery_to_gcs import (
    BigQueryToGCSOperator,
  
data_to_gcs = BigQueryToGCSOperator(
        task_id="BigQuery_to_GoogleCloudBucket",
        gcp_conn_id="google_cloud_default",
        project_id=project_id,
        source_project_dataset_table=f"{project_id}.{temp_dataset_id}.{temp_table}",
        location="EU",
        print_header=True,
        destination_cloud_storage_uris=destination_uri,
        export_format="CSV",
        field_delimiter="|",
    )
```

I saw this code snippet in the `Airflow` code, and I think it can cause an issue if you set the `export_format` with `csv` as lowercase value :

```py
if self.export_format == 'CSV':
     # Only set fieldDelimiter and printHeader fields if using CSV.
     # Google does not like it if you set these fields for other export
     # formats.
     configuration['extract']['fieldDelimiter'] = self.field_delimiter
     configuration['extract']['printHeader'] = self.print_header
```

In your case, this code snippet is not invoked and the operator take the default value for `field_delimiter` which is `,`

Here you can see the default values used in the constructor of this operator in the `Airflow` code :

```py
def __init__(
    self,
    *,
    source_project_dataset_table: str,
    destination_cloud_storage_uris: List[str],
    compression: str = 'NONE',
    export_format: str = 'CSV',
    field_delimiter: str = ',',
    print_header: bool = True,
    gcp_conn_id: str = 'google_cloud_default',
    bigquery_conn_id: Optional[str] = None,
    delegate_to: Optional[str] = None,
    labels: Optional[Dict] = None,
    location: Optional[str] = None,
    impersonation_chain: Optional[Union[str, Sequence[str]]] = None,
    **kwargs,
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. This was indeed the issue.